# Windows Phone 8 timezone localization

Tags: windows-phone-8

Example (Windows Phone 8 - changing languages)

1. Sending a time zone of "Pacific Standard Time" back to my web service and
   calling the method below works fine.

   ```
   var TimeZone TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZone);
   ```
2. Changing the phone language to Spanish and sending back "Hora estandar, Pacifico"
   which is the same time zone in Spanish fails.

   TimeZoneInfo for Windows Phone does not seem to provide access to the English version
   of the time zone when the language is set to Spanish.

Comment: Do you have to send the string up? Can you get by sending the TimeZoneOFfset, UTC time, or a DateTimeOffset object. All of which allow you to know the local time.

Comment: Using the offset would get you in the ballpark, but the ambiguity of the large number and time zones through the world would be unreliable.

Comment: In reviewing the source code for TimeZoneInfo.cs Microsoft does have a m_id private member variable that does have the English version of the time zone, but it is not accessible.